# Why does this lambda-related type inference fail?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, type-inference

I would like to understand why the following fails to work with an "reference is ambiguous" when it seems that it shouldn't be. Is it worth reporting to the javac team?

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.ToLongFunction;
import org.junit.Test;

public class LambdaTest {

    @FunctionalInterface
    public static interface CheckedFunction<U,R>
    {
        R apply(U value) throws Exception;
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public static interface CheckedToLongFunction<T>
    {
        long apply(T i) throws Exception;
    }

    public static <T,R> Function<T,R> unchecked(CheckedFunction<T,R> func)
    {
        return value -> {
            try
            {
                return func.apply (value);
            }
            catch(RuntimeException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }

    public static <T> ToLongFunction<T> unchecked(CheckedToLongFunction<T> func)
    {
        return value -> {
            try
            {
                return func.apply (value);
            }
            catch(RuntimeException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }

      public void 
    bar( Function<Object,Object> fn ) { 

            System.out.println("Function"); 
        }

      @Test public void
    test() {

            bar (a -> a); //OK
            bar (unchecked (a -> a)); //Should be OK, but receive "reference to unchecked is ambiguous"
            bar (unchecked ((Object a) -> a)); //OK
        }

}
```

As you can see, the example is interesting because both `CheckedFunction` and `CheckedToLongFunction` take a reference type, so explicitly specifying the lamba's input type seems to add nothing useful. Yet, it lets the code compile.

The `unckeched(CheckedFunction)` should be called without ambiguity, because `unchecked(CheckedToLongFunction)` yields a lambda that returns a primitive, while bar needs an `Object`.

I am especially looking for a resolution from the JLS. If the JLS doesn't specify this, I can try filing it as a javac bug.

Answer (score 2):

You have two methods

```
public static <T,R> Function<T,R> unchecked(CheckedFunction<T,R> func)
public static <T> ToLongFunction<T> unchecked(CheckedToLongFunction<T> func)
```

Each have a parameter of a functional interface type.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public static interface CheckedFunction<U, R> {
    R apply(U value) throws Exception;
}

@FunctionalInterface
public static interface CheckedToLongFunction<T> {
    long apply(T i) throws Exception;
}
```

The [implicitly typed lambda expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.1) `a -> a` can be applied to either of those, given the proper context. However, that context does not seem to be checked when doing overload resolution.

So although the `a -> a` in

```
bar(unchecked(a -> a)); // Should be OK, but receive
```

could not be converted to a `CheckedToLongFunction` instance (since a type argument of `Long` could not be inferred from that invocation context), the lambda is still applicable to the functional type.

The compiler simply can't determine if it should convert the `a -> a` to a `CheckedToLongFunction` or to a `CheckedFunction`. As both are applicable, the invocation is ambiguous. The invocation context (and return types) aren't checked to resolve the ambiguity.

In this case, however,

```
bar(unchecked((Object a) -> a)); // OK
```

we have an *explicitly typed* lambda expression. The lambda body resolves to an return value of type `Object`, which does not fit the requirements of `CheckedToLongFunction#apply(..)` method, ie. an expression of type `Object` cannot be implicitly converted to an expression of type `long`.

Therefore, and since there's one other applicable method, that one is chosen.

Comment: Actually,  `bar (unchecked (a -> new Object()))` does not work either, so it's not an issue of specifying the return type. You say the invocation context is not checked. Why not? It almost looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky The lambda expression `a -> new Object()` is still _implicitly typed_. The compiler will only go so far. Because it is implicitly typed, it won't check the type of the body of the expression. Why? [Read this.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.1) Seems like, because the invocation can be standalone, ie. not used as an argument or assignment to anything else, we don't want to have 2 different ways (rulesets) for evaluating it.

Answer (score 1):

The function declaration `unchecked(CheckedToLongFunction<T> func)` is intended to return a `ToLongFunction`, the `ToLongFunction` returns a `long`. In your argument, you claim that this function should be ignored because it returns a primitive (and perhaps a Runtime exception is thrown).

With the introduction of Auto-Boxing though, the primitive result from `ToLongFunction` can be boxed to a `Long`, making it an object.

Thus, in the same context as it is already, the ToLongFunction can return both a `Long` and a `long`

Thus the ambiguous function.

See [JLS 15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)

> 1 - The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.

Then

> 2- The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while allowing boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the third phase.

Comment: The type `ToLongFunction` shouldn't be in the picture here. It's the invocation of `unchecked` that's ambiguous. And in any case, `bar` expects a `Function`, not a `ToLongFunction`.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the resolution works fine if the lambda's *input* type is specified. Specifying the input type does not resolve any auto-boxing-caused ambiguity, therefore it is not a factor.